# -[GCKCastDeviceProvider stopDiscovery] must be called on main thread

Tags: ios, multithreading, chromecast

In react native using the google cast sdk 3 everything we reload the app get crash and the error is -[GCKCastDeviceProvider stopDiscovery] must be called on main thread

We put all the code inside:

```
   dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ 
     // my code block
   });
```

We also check if really on the main thread with this:

```
 if ([NSThread isMainThread]) {
    NSLog(@"on main thread");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Based from this [release note](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/release-notes#november-21-2016), all methods in [`CastContext`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/cast/framework/CastContext.html) that your app calls must be called from the main thread, otherwise an `Exception` will be thrown. Also, this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/ios_sender_integrate#call_methods_from_main_thread) stated that all SDK methods must be called from the main thread.

Comment: That's right, problem is that stopDiscovery is called itself, it doesn't call anywhere in the code...